# Algorithm to differentiate between color change and brightness change for a given pixel

Tags: android, opencv

I am using OpenCV in my Android app to read pixel values and determine whether there is a new object on screen in that particular pixel. Now when I read a pixel value, the RGB values could be different when there is a new object in frame or if the overall brightness of the frame has increased or reduced. Can someone suggest me some techniques that can be used to differentiate them?

Currently I compare difference in RGB values, if R value has increased or decreased considerably more the blue and green and so on. Which is just 60-70% accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The `Color` class has a static method called `colorToHSV` which will do a RGB -> HSV conversion.  HSV is Hue/Saturation/Value where value is another term for brightness.

The signature is: `public static void colorToHSV (int color, float[] hsv)`

Here `hsv[2]` would be the brightness value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using cvtcolor on the image and convert the RGB image to Lab/Luv/HSV. I have worked on a similar project before and to make it much more accurate (93% accuracy) we saved all possible colors to an image and trained a classifier (SVM, NN and so on; they are all very easy to implement in OpenCV) with the "groundtruth" and we used Luv color space. I know you don't want to correct the change. I'm just mentioning it because we got the highest accuracy with Luv ( more than for HSV and Lab). [See here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) make sure to be correct with the conversions of RGB to Lab according to OpenCV and not [this](http://www.color-hex.com/) as it isn't same. 
Hope it helps.